# How to properly use nginx echo support to respond with a 504 inline page?

Tags: nginx, http

I am trying to reply with a custom 504 page by using nginx echo support but for some strange reason when this is active the browser downloads the response instead of opening it.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    server_name  localhost;

    location @fallback {
        add_header Content-Type "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
        add_header Content-Disposition 'inline; filename="504.html"';

        # when this line is enabled I get the download behavior!
        # when this is not active, I get a 200 response, which is not desired                      
        echo_status 504;

        echo "<!DOCTYPE html>";
        echo "<html lang='en'>";
        echo "  <head>";
        echo "    <meta charset='utf-8'>";
        echo "    <title>Backend is down</title>";
        echo "  </head>";
        echo "  <body>";
        echo "    Backend service is offline, please retry in few minutes. $echo_timer_elapsed";
        echo "  </body>";
        echo "</html>";
    }

    location / {
        error_page 502 504 = @fallback;
        proxy_connect_timeout   10s;
        proxy_pass        http://google.com:1234;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey I was testing the echo module today with a similar config for a custom "403"...

I was failing to read the docs properly and googling lead me to you're question.

Se: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule#Content_Handler_Directives

Instead of using add_header Content-Type try:

default_type "text/html; charset=UTF-8";

I'm not sure if the add_header should be expected to work, but its not mentioned in the module manual. [edit]: also the default_type is most likely already set in the nginx global conf to:  default_type  application/octet-stream; I was forgetting that, so its still best to change it here if you want to see a response in the browser.[/edit]

*Note: You should still keep the "echo_status 504;" if you don't want to see get "200" response.

Comment: add_header only works when the response code is 200, 201, 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, or 307.